# Configuring nginx to map pgadmin to a URI

Tags: nginx, pgadmin

I have an `nginx` and a `pgadmin` Docker container connected to each other. Only `nginx` container is exposed to the outside. How can I map `pgadmin` to a sub URI?

If the host is `example.com`, I want the `pgadmin` to be reachable at `example.com/pgadmin/`. So far, I have this in my `nginx.conf` file:

```
location ^~ /pgadmin/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://pgadmin:80/;
}
```

A request to `example.com/pgadmin/` goes through to `pgadmin` but when pgadmin redirects to the login page, it redirects to `example.com/login?next=%2F`, not to `example.com/pgadmin/login?next=%2F`.

How can I make `pgadmin` to work at `example.com/pgadmin`?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to map `http://pgadmin:80/` to `http://example.com/pgadmin/`.
Add the below entry in your hosts file to map pgadmin to example.com

```
pgadmin    example.com
```

Now to map the `:80` to `/pgadmin`, add the following in your nginx.conf :

```
location /pgadmin {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://pgadmin:80/;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Just want to make sure that `pgadmin` is only accessible from the `nginx` container.

Comment: Yes. Have you restarted the nginx service after the config change?  Try `/etc/init.d/nginx reload`

Comment: I did,still no joy.